# Application did not respond

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

i've been trying to code a ranked discord bot and i managed to code it but when i run the bot and try to set it up in my discord server it gives me this error saying 'application did not respond' can someone please help me figure this out i'm not even sure if the code will do the job but it's my first project and i just started learning how to code so if theres anything wrong feel free to tell me

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
  ]
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

const Enmap = require('enmap');
const prefix = '-'; // Change this to your desired prefix
const queues = new Enmap({ name: 'queues' });
const rankings = new Enmap({ name: 'rankings' });

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  // Command to check rank
  if (command === 'rank') {
    const playerID = message.author.id;
    const playerRank = rankings.get(playerID) || 0;
    message.reply(`Your rank is ${playerRank}`);
  }

  // New command: Setup with -sett
  if (command === '-sett') {
    try {
      const channel = await message.guild.channels.create('Queue', { type: 'GUILD_TEXT' });

      const joinButton = new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setCustomId('join_queue')
        .setLabel('Join Queue')
        .setStyle('PRIMARY');

      const leaveButton = new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setCustomId('leave_queue')
        .setLabel('Leave Queue')
        .setStyle('DANGER');

      const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(joinButton, leaveButton);

      const queueMessage = await channel.send({ content: 'Click a button to join or leave the queue:', components: [row] });

      // Store queue message and channel id for future reference
      queues.set('queue_message', queueMessage.id);
      queues.set('queue_channel', channel.id);

      // Inform setup completion
      message.reply('Queue setup completed.');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error during setup:', err);
      message.reply('There was an error during setup.');
    }
  }
});

const YOUR_BOT_TOKEN = '';
const YOUR_APPLICATION_ID = '';
const YOUR_GUILD_ID = '';

client.login(YOUR_BOT_TOKEN);

const commands = [
  {
    name: 'sett',
    description: 'Set up the queue system',
    type: 1,
  },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(YOUR_BOT_TOKEN);

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

    await rest.put(
      Routes.applicationGuildCommands(YOUR_APPLICATION_ID, YOUR_GUILD_ID),
      { body: commands },
    );

    console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

I tried everything but i cant seem to find where the problem is

Comment: Please edit to include the full error message. May require adding more error handling - should be something like `DiscordClient.on('error' ...` since it's event-based.

Comment: i did that but nothing has changed. I'm new to this..i really barely understand anything but i'm so interested and i want to learn more about it. i watched a video of a guy who made an elo discord bot and i got inspired to make one so ive been asking chatgpt alot and learnt some things the bot i'm trying to copy is called NeatQueue which is like perfect for the game i'm play and i'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me learn how to code discord bots

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT screwed this up, based on [current documentation](https://discordjs.guide/). There's a current version of the imports in [this example](https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/main/code-samples/creating-your-bot/initial-files/index.js), but since it's ChatGPT-generated there's likely to be more issues at some point. I'm guessing you have replaced the YOUR_BOT_TOKEN, YOUR_APPLICATION_ID, YOUR_GUILD_ID in your local version of the code? If not, that would be the next thing to look into, but make sure not to share those values publicly.

Comment: yes i replaced everything and i tried doing it with  Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS and  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES but it didn't work it always gives me an error when i run the program and when i run the program with this code there doesnt seem to be any problems i don't get any errors in my code and the bot gets online but what i don't understand is that when i try setting the bot up it gives me the error that says 'the application did not respond' for some reason

Comment: You mean when you run this [as on this page](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/main-file.html#running-your-application) it says "Ready!"? I haven't done this before, but the official documentation is doing it differently. So, ChatGPT either used an old version of the code which would require you to install that version to get this to work, or mixed in some other Discord bot coding style which will probably never work. Was the error different after changing the imports & intents to follow the docs?

Comment: when i node the bot it says 
Started refreshing application (/) commands.
Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.
Logged in as 'the bot'
and when i tried with the intents it keeps giving me an error that says unidentified intents for some reason but i changed it to 
GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, and it worked and i really dont know what chatgpt did but the code seems to be working fine theres a problem in the execution of the code i guess it keeps saying 'application did not respond' but no errors in the console

Comment: Followed the getting started guide from the docs and got it working with their code. The "Application did not respond" error is because the bot has to be running (`node index.js` and don't `Ctrl + C` to kill it until after testing) to be able to respond. While AI is capable of generating code it can not in general be trusted to write useful code beyond a pretty simple single line.

Comment: i tried that but it still gives me the same error even when the bot is running i think theres a problem with the code i'll try taking a look if i can fix anything in it otherwise i really dont know what to do

Comment: Yeah, it's almost definitely the code. Would be simple to fix by replacing stuff with the examples from the official docs, but there's bound to be more problems down the line that will require debugging, which means you'll need to learn JS and subsequently NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you aren't handling button interactions. Discord shows "The application did not respond" to clients because Discord never received a response to the button interactions sent to your bot.

You need to setup an [`interactionCreate`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-interactionCreate) event handler, and make sure to `reply` to the interaction inside the handler.

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    // Filter out other interaction types
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

    // Extract important properties
    const { customId } = interaction;

    // Perform an action based on customId
    switch (customId) {
        case 'join_queue':
            // Add user to queue
            interaction.reply('Added to queue!');
            break;
        case 'leave_queue':
            // Remove user from queue
            interaction.reply('Removed from queue!');
            break;
    }
});
```

I highly recommend using this code pattern for each interaction type you handle, and for `messageCreate` too. Leave a comment if you want to know more.

Comment: uh i honestly tried everything but it never seems to work i got to a point where i gave up on that project cuz i never found where the problem is and i tried that aswell but same problem its always 'bot did not respond' its not receiving the commands for some reason that i dont understand

Comment: I think you should try using the code outline I provided in my answer before giving up.